# PHP and JavaScript redirect not working

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    require_once 'assets/functions.php';
    if(isset($_SESSION['userName'])){
        header('Location:http://192.168.0.50/hub.php');
        die();
    }
    $title = 'ResRes - Login';
    printCSS($title);
?>
```

Which is part of my index.php file. The problem is that after loading, neither `window.location = result.location` or the `header('Location:http://192.168.0.50/hub.php')` work. This is getting quite frustrating.

My javascript code is:

```
function verifyUser(userEmail){
    $.getJSON('verifyUser.php', {data : userEmail}
    ).done(function(result){
        window.location.href = result.location;
        alert(result.message);
        console.log(result);
        return false;
    });
};
```

I suspect that the `.done(function(result){...})` is not even executing, since no console.log() occurs nor the alert itself. No idea why it is having that behaviour.

Also, just to make sure, in my verifyUser.php file I have the following header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

On the test server, and on wamp server this does not happen. It gets redirected. In this production server, however, it does not redirect. User has to manually refresh the page to be sent to `result.location` or what the header on index.php says.

Any ideas what might be happening?

**EDIT**
Perform the `$.getJSON` manually on console, outputs this:

```
$.get('verifyUser.php', {data : 'hector.admin@laestanciaschool.com'}).done(function(result) { console.log("Done called", result); });
Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
```

Comment: Are you getting a javascript error in the console? Try returning the URL in JSON (server side), then setting the window to that location in javascript.

Comment: If its working on 2 out of 3 servers I am guessing your code isn't the problem. It is probably a server configuration issue. Check your php.ini file maybe there's some differences between the 3 instance of PHP. If I am correct some option that need to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try replacing

```
window.location.href = result.location
```

with

```
window.open(result.location, "_self")
```

Also, do you have sessions enabled in your php.ini file?

Comment: your answer doesn't work. I suspect that `.done(function())` is not being executed.

Comment: @hsoto can you `console.log(result)` and see what you get?

Comment: Nope. I updated my answer to reflect that right now. Nothing is being alerted or console.log()' ing. Really weird.

Comment: @hsoto Just curious. What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: 1.11.1, the stable, for production one.

Comment: Try using `$.get('verifyUser.php', {data : userEmail}).done(function(result) { console.log("Done called", result); });` Let me know if that outputs anything.

Comment: `$.get('verifyUser.php', {data : 'hector.admin@laestanciaschool.com'}).done(function(result) { console.log("Done called", result); });
Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}` this is what is output. No console.log. Updated my answer to reflect that. If I use the .fail, my updated answer says what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58817/discussion-between-gcr15-and-hsoto).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the js debugger of your browser to insert breakpoint to see what's wrong.

With chrome, press `F12` and click the `Sources` Tab, and then find you source file, insert breakpoint by left-clicking the left-side of the line of code.

You could also check the request and response between the browser and your server with the `Network` Tab

Comment: I did as you said, apparently, it skips the `.done()` part. The returned data is correct. There's no problem on that. It returns the JSON just as expected.

Comment: @hsoto Then the fail handler must be called, add `.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) { var err = textStatus + ", " + error; console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );` and try again. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: This is what happens: 

`Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected token h VM23763:10`

Comment: I've read the documentation ample times. I'm not a newbie on this. I've been using this for quite a while now. This is the first time I get an error of this sort.

Comment: I guess the json response from your server may hava SyntaxError. Capture the response from the `Network` and verify the syntax on your `Console`.